# GCC_PHAT output

Tags: android, audio, signal-processing

I am trying to develop [GCC_PHAT](http://www.xavieranguera.com/phdthesis/node92.html) algorithm on Android devices. 
For FFT I used [this library](http://www.nayuki.io/res/free-small-fft-in-multiple-languages/Fft.java).
The idea is to correlate two audio files (16-bit PCM mono) to find the delay between them. With Matlab it works perfectly.
My first problem is FFT output, it gives numbers higher than `32768`. For example:

```
fft re   -20830.895138576154
fft re   -30639.569794501647
fft re   -49850.48597621472
fft re   -49335.28275604235
fft re   -96060.94916529073
fft re   -91409.17426504416
fft re   -226903.051428709
```

Is there a way to normalize these numbers to an interval of [-1,1]?

Comment: Any particular reasons why you need the FFT (an intermediate result) to be normalized? From what I understand the output G_PHAT is normalized to the [-1,1] range by definition.

Comment: yes after normalization, GCC=conv/(max(abs(conv),1e-6)) the values are scaled between -1 and 1. but again, i have to apply IFFT to these results, which gives me non normalized numbers like you saw above in the FFT. So, i dont know if the returned index of the maximum peak correponding to a such value is true or not.

Comment: Unless I misundersood, d_PHAT as the returned index is limited to [0,N-1] range (where N is the size of the FFT). The actual value of the peak is not significant unless you wish to perform other kinds of processing on R_PHAT (in which case, you might want to clarify what kind of processing you intend on doing). Off hand, choosing the maximum over all (i,j) pairs as the normalization factor could achieve what you are looking for, but whether this is the most suitable for you specific application is another story.

Comment: yes i will do further processing after the GCC_PHAT to compute the distance between two devices sending these audio signals. Besides, i want to compare the value of the peak pointed by that index to the one in Matlab. in Android, i found a value of 921.28018.., and as i said in matlab there will be values <1.0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [library's forward transform definition](http://www.nayuki.io/page/free-small-fft-in-multiple-languages#MathJax-Element-2-Frame) does match [Matlab](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fft.html)'s, so you should get matching values after the forward transform (not that it is critical since G_PHAT does get normalized to [-1,1]).

However, the same cannot be said of the [inverse transform](http://www.nayuki.io/page/free-small-fft-in-multiple-languages#MathJax-Element-3-Frame). Indeed from 
the code comments on `inverseTransform`:

> This transform does not perform scaling, so the inverse is not a true inverse.

And from the library webpage:

> This FFT does not perform any scaling. So for a vector of length *n*, after performing a transform and an inverse transform on it, the result will be the original vector multiplied by *n* (plus approximation errors).

So, to get values matching Matlab's FFT/IFFT implementation you would need to divide the result of the IFFT by *n*.